# Does the Peg.js engine backstep after a lookahead like regexs do?

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, pegjs

According to regular-expressions.info on lookarounds, the engine backsteps after a lookahead:

> Let's take one more look inside, to make sure you understand the
>   implications of the lookahead. Let's apply q(?=u)i to quit. The
>   lookahead is now positive and is followed by another token. Again, q
>   matches q and u matches u. Again, the match from the lookahead must be
>   discarded, so the engine steps back from i in the string to u. The
>   lookahead was successful, so the engine continues with i. But i cannot
>   match u. So this match attempt fails. All remaining attempts fail as
>   well, because there are no more q's in the string.

However, in Peg.js it *SEEMS* like the engine still moves passed the `&` or `!` so that in fact it isn't a lookahead in the same sense as regexps but a decision on consumption, and there is no backstepping, and therefor no true looking ahead.

Is this the case?

(If so then certain parsearen't even possible, like [this one](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/9pbgmh/regexp_engine_vs_pegjs_engine_and_parsing_in/)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookahead works similar to how it does in a regex engine.

This query fails to match because the next letter should be `'u'`, not `'i'`.

```
word = 'q' &'u' 'i' 't'
```

This query succeeds:

```
word = 'q' &'u' 'u' 'i' 't'
```

This query succeeds:

```
word = 'q' 'u' 'i' 't'
```

As for your example, try something along these lines, you shouldn't need to use lookaheads at all:

```
expression
    = termPair ( _ delimiter _ termPair )*

termPair
    = term ('.' term)? ' ' term ('.' term)?

term "term"
    = $([a-z0-9]+)

delimiter "delimiter"
    = "."

_ "whitespace"
    = [ \t\n\r]+
```

**EDIT**: Added another example per comments below.

```
expression
    = first:term rest:delimTerm* { return [first].concat(rest); }

delimTerm
    = delimiter t:term { return t; }

term "term"
    = $((!delimiter [a-z0-9. ])+)

delimiter "delimiter"
    = _ "." _

_ "whitespace"
    = [ \t\n\r]+
```

**EDIT**: Added extra explanation of the term expression.

I'll try to break down the term rule a bit `$((!delimiter [a-z0-9. ])+)`.

`$()` converts everything inside to a single text node like `[].join('')`.

A single "character" of a term is any character `[a-z0-9. ]`, if we wanted to simplify it, we could say `.` instead. Before matching the character we want to lookahead for a `delimiter`, if we find a `delimiter` we stop matching that character. Since we want multiple characters we do the whole thing multiple times with `+`.

It think it's a common idiom in PEG parsers to move forward this way. I learned the idea from the [treetop](http://cjheath.github.io/treetop/pitfalls_and_advanced_techniques.html) documentation for matching a string.

Comment: The crux, however, is having the delimiting value includable in the term. So, if the delimiter is "  .  " (space dot space) can you also have terms like: "term1.a term1.b". An example expression would be "term1.a term1.b . term2.a term2.b" For a human, this is readily parsable, the space-surrounded dot is the clear delimiter, but Peg.js do it is the question.

Comment: Both of those examples parse in the answer above. I'm not sure what you are asking about specifically.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. It's not dynamic though. The term should be any combination of any amount of letter, dots, spaces. Then the space-dot-space delimiter and another term like that. The spaces in the terms of your example are not dynamic. So as a term the following should also be allowable: "a.1 b cde.1 cde2 . this entire sentence including its ending period is a term too." There are two terms and one delimiter after 'cde2'. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I took another stab at it in the **EDIT** above. You can use a negative lookahead for `delimiter` within your `term` to avoid being overly greedy when grabbing periods.

Comment: Wow. I tried to do this 1000 times. Thanks for proving that it was me, not the parser and for giving me something to study. Incredible!

Comment: Can you add a walk-though of the term rule? EDIT: how did you come up with this?

Comment: Hope that helps, I added a little more info.